# R - Exporting plot - gsub() issue

Tags: string, plot, utf-8, gsub

I have a problem with exporting/saving plots in R. It is quite interesting because it started after I downloaded R 4.3.2 (Windows).

```
numbers <- c(20, 80, 110, 70, 98, 100, 215, 65)
plot(numbers)
```

Yes, it is easy. But, exporting the plot is impossible.
I have tried Export > Save as image (default) ... And I have got that: *Error in gsub("%%", "", s, fixed = TRUE) : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8*.

I have the same problem with Shiny.
I guess R doesn't like the location. Because 'Desktop' is 'Masaüstü" in my language.
Has anyone had a problem like this before?

I can not change my computer language (I don't want to do it).